# Firemonkey animate DAE 3D model (with animation key) in Delphi Xe6

Tags: delphi, animation, firemonkey, collada

I have a DAE 3Dmodel (collada) with animation key in my 3D model.

I tried to import to the Delphi Xe6 within the following steps :

1. File -> New -> "Firemonkey Desktop Apllication - Delphi"
2. Select "3D Firemonkey Application"
3. Add a "tmodel3d" and assign my DAE 3D model into "MeshCollection". (http://www.sidhiciang.com/myfiles/test.DAE)

The 3D Model shows up. But....

How to make the FireMonkey show the animated key from my DAE 3D Model ? 
Eg : How to show the animation I set from key 1 to 20 from my DAE 3D model ?

PS : The DAE 3D Model is imported from 3D Studio Max. So if the DAE is not the one, then I can import it to ASE.

Answer (score 0):

Collada files can have built-in animation data with "bones" and "animation keys" that some 3D software can understand.

Firemonkey doesn't support anything like that in any 3D files.
Firemonkey can only import the meshes from these files. Firemonkey animation is limited to changing certain basic properties of the object.

Comment: In that case do you know how to play the animation from DAE model in delphi ?